# WebSphere MQ: Consuming Messages in Batches

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq

Is there a way to consume messages from a WebSphere MQ queue in batches? e.g.

```
messages = queue.receiveBatch( BATCH_SIZE )
```

Where it would return a collection of messages ( e.g. List[Message] ) up to a `BATCH_SIZE` in a **single "receive"**?

( *I can call receive `BATCH_SIZE` times within a transaction, but that is not what I am looking for* )

If [message groups](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fac25700_.htm) can solve it, what would it look like? Although it does not seem to be the right solution as "message groups" seem to be reading messages one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  WMQ has read-ahead in which non-persistent messages are streamed to the client but even there the client executes a single `GET` (or language equivalent) per message.

One of the attributes of async messaging is supposed to be that messages are atomic.  Any dependency of messages on other messages is called an affinity and message affinities break the async model. (However every transport makes some accommodation for affinities and message grouping is an example of that.)  So a `GET` is the atomic unit of work which has a 1:1 correspondence to a message.

WMQ messages can be of arbitrary size up to 100MB and messages larger than that can be segmented where one logical message is split across multiple physical messages.  In the case of a segmented message, one `GET` will result in consumption of multiple messages, however to the app only one logical message is returned.

WMQ Channels use batches and until recently these were constructed strictly by message count.  However the aforementioned variability in message sizes made tuning channels extremely difficult if both large and small messages traversed the same channel.  In v7.1 of WMQ channel batches now are bounded by a message count or a byte count, whichever is hit first.  Any notion of message `GET` batching would require similar tuning functionality in order to prevent severe impacts to memory.  There would be additional interactions with logging, queue sizes, etc.  Note also that if one message failed, the entire batch would have to be rolled back.

If the intent is to improve performance, use transactions.  When receiving messages under syncpoint you can tune the number of messages to `GET` between `COMMIT` calls.  You can considerably improve performance with `COMMIT` intervals > 1, however this falls off above a threshold which you can determine with a bit of trial and error.  The Performance Reports can help determine the best number for your platform.  These are available from the [SupportPacs main page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).  Look for the entries with names like MPxx.

If the messages are non-persistent and you can afford to lose some of them on disconnect, then you can use read-ahead - assuming you have a modern version of WMQ.  This will stream messages to the application's WMQ client so that the next message is already in the local buffer when `GET` is called.

By the way, the link in the original post was to the WMB docs.  The WMQ docs can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/library/).

Comment: that's a heck of an answer => thanks a lot! I am indeed looking to design for consumption performance. It needs to read X messages that would participate in XA transaction => need to be _persisted to DB_ as well as _transformed_ and _sent_ to a different queue (all in the same tx). The messages I am dealing with _are_ persistent, is there any cool streaming features (e.g. "read-ahead") for persistent messages?

Comment: No, the deal with read-ahead is that if the client ends, there's no way to roll back the messages.  That quality of service is not appropriate for persistent messages.  If you made them persistent WMQ doesn't want to take chances with losing them.  On the other hand, the client cannot get them under syncpoint since only the app knows about message flows, message affinities, etc.  One poison message could potentially cause an entire batch to requeue since they would all increment their redelivery counters at the same time.

Comment: By the way, if you are doing XA transactions and coordinating with the DB then you must either use WebSphere App Server (which knows how to be an XA coordinator with the WMQ client) or the WMQ Extended Transactional Client.  The WMQ base client can only perform single-phase commit with non-IBM app servers.